# angular, after getting promise value cannot access the value in another function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form, and want to add default values to the form fields after shows up, so basically I have 2 function #1 for retrieving data from backend #2 display the form:

```
person$: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPersonData(123)
  this.buildPersonForm()
}

getPersonData(id: number) {
   this.personService.getDetails(id)
     .subscribe((data) => {
       this.person$ = data
     }
}

buildPersonForm() {

  // Here I want to access this.person$.firstname

  console.log(this.person$.firstname) // undefined
  this.PersonForm = this.fb.group({
     firstname: [null, Validators.required],
  })
}
```

in html template if I use it as below it works:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Firstname" formControlName="firstname" value="{{person$?.firstname}}">
```

but I want to know how to access it inside component itself not in html template.

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.2
@schematics/angular          7.0.2
@schematics/update           0.10.2
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.3
```

Comment: Then you should be calling `this.buildPersonForm()` under `getPersonData()` subscription

Answer (score 1):

Simply just call `buildPersonForm` on getPersonData observable complete

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPersonData(123);
}

getPersonData(id: number) {
   this.personService.getDetails(id)
     .subscribe((data) => {
        this.person$ = data
      },
     null,
      () => this.buildPersonForm()
    }
```

Another way just but `buildPersonForm` in the body of next method in subscribe

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPersonData(123);
}

getPersonData(id: number) {
   this.personService.getDetails(id)
     .subscribe((data) => {
       this.person$ = data;
       this.buildPersonForm();
     }
}
```

Last way you can use **async/await**

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.person$ = await this.getPersonData(123).toPromise();
  this.buildPersonForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FormControl will take the default value in the first item to the array as described below.

For this we can use **async/await**.

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.person$ = await this.personService.getDetails(id).toPromise();
    this.buildPersonForm();
}
```

And then we can set the value to the FormControl in the "**buildPersonForm()**" method.

```
this.PersonForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: [this.person$.firstname, Validators.required],
})
```

and the in the html the **value** binding in not required, if you have added "**formControlName**" as described.

```
<input matInput placeholder="Firstname" formControlName="firstname">
```

Comment: I know I can add default value in the component itself, but the problem is I cannot access the retrieved data from `getPersonData()`

Comment: I have tried it before posting the question, but since the html form is part of default DOM to be rendered by angular, so I got undefined also, I think angular is not waiting till the `getPersonData()` is done with its job the go to `buildPersonForm()`

Comment: @mos of course angular will not wait for an asynchronous call (and this is desired). If you want to do something when your asynchronous call is over, then do it at the place where you get the data from the async call